# Can't get my difficulty level to load on my Android game

Tags: java, android

Basically I have to make a maths game with easy/medium/hard difficulties. I used the switch statement to achieve this which calls a method that deals with what to do in each difficulty.

The problem is that I can't get my head around what this method with the switch statement should return, if anything, and how should I call it in the onCreate method. Also I don't know why, but the TextView in the getPuzzle method is giving me an error when I call the tv.setText method on it.

```
public class Game extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "Brain Training";

    public static final String KEY_DIFFICULTY = "com.coursework.braintrain.difficulty";
    public static final int DIFFICULTY_EASY = 0;
    public static final int DIFFICULTY_MEDIUM = 1;
    public static final int DIFFICULTY_HARD = 2;
    public static final int DIFFICULTY_GURU = 3;


    private int brain;




    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    int diff = getIntent().getIntExtra(KEY_DIFFICULTY, DIFFICULTY_EASY);
    setBrain(getPuzzle(diff));
    getBrain();


    setContentView(R.layout.gamelayout);


    final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.USERentry);


    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            //String buttonText = (String) button.getText();
            edittext.setText(edittext.getText() + "1");
            //edittext.setText() = edittext.getText() + "1";
        }
    });
    //rest of the bottons...
}


public void Easy12(){
    int a = (int) Math.random();
    int b = (int) Math.random();
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_label);
    String aString = Integer.toString(a);
    String bString = Integer.toString(b);
    String display = aString + bString;
    tv.setText(display);

}

private int getPuzzle(int diff){

    //TODO: Continue last game
    switch(diff){
    case DIFFICULTY_HARD:

        break;
    case DIFFICULTY_MEDIUM:

        break;
    case DIFFICULTY_EASY:
        Easy12();
        break;
    default: Easy12();
    }
    //might require to return an array or something
    return diff;


}


public int getBrain() {
    return brain;
}


public void setBrain(int brain) {
    this.brain = brain;
}


}
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here's the xml file that goes along with it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
              android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/question_label"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Hello" />
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/USERentry"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
    android:textColor="@color/user_txt_color"/>"
    <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/keypad"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*">
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_1"
            android:text="1">
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_2"
            android:text="2"
            android:onClick="">
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_3"
            android:text="3">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_4"
            android:text="4">
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_5"
            android:text="5">
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_6"
            android:text="6">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
       <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_7"
            android:text="7">
        </Button> 
        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_8"
            android:text="8">
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_9"
            android:text="9">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_0"
            android:text="0">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_del"
            android:text="del">
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_minus"
            android:text="-">
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_hash"
            android:text="#">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting with the text view?

Comment: It's on the tv.setText(display) call. I have no idea why its giving me it.

Comment: Presumably you are getting an error in log cat though. What does it actually say?

Comment: Okayy I think I've found the problem (it won't let me go as far as seeing it working in the emulator because it gives me back errors for the other problems). In my XML file, in my TextView properties I said android:text="xxxx" which meant it was hard-coded, so I couldn't change its text. I took that out and hopefully that part is fixed, just need to figure out the other bit that's not working. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: android:text="xxxx" doesn't mean that it is unchangable. That just gives it a default value. You need to learn about logcat before you can get any more help here. We cannot know how to help you unless you give us some details on the error.

Comment: 03-05 09:48:11.677: E/AndroidRuntime(549): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException  
03-05 09:48:11.677: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at com.coursework.braintrain.Game.Easy12(Game.java:160)  
03-05 09:48:11.677: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at com.coursework.braintrain.Game.getPuzzle(Game.java:175)  
03-05 09:48:11.677: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at com.coursework.braintrain.Game.onCreate(Game.java:37)  
03-05 09:48:11.677: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)  
is that the kinda stuff you were looking for from the logcat? Sorry for bad formatting

Comment: This is what we were looking for from logcat, and it's what you should look at to! It tells you the problem (null pointer exception) and the line number (160 in the file game.java). If you post this information in future questions, people should be able to help faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a null pointer exception in the `Easy12()` method. As suggested by Knossos, this looks likely to be caused by `question_label` not existing in your xml layout. Make sure your xml contains something that looks like this:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/question_label"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Hello" />
```

You can still change the text of a TextView at runtime with the `setText()` method, the `android:text` attribute is just an initial value.

If you still can't get it working or see the problem, post your xml layout as well. If this was the problem, you might want to consider reading http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html to understand xml layouts and how to use them a bit more.

Comment: Hi there, I've posted my xml code above, it doesn't seem to be the problem. I tried just leaving the the parameters for setText() as just integers but that doesn't work either. I hope you guys can help. Thanks for the help so far

Comment: Okay so I think the actual problem is the program not recognizing the TextView. I tried doing tv.setId(R.id.question_label); and it still returned the error at that line. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

onCreate() is a method in the class Activity. You are overriding it, providing your own Activity initialisation code and using super.onCreate() to allow the onCreate() from Activity to run also.

Please see this link about the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

getPuzzle() returns the same value that you originally send to it. So the return is essentially pointless.

It looks like the point of the getPuzzle() function is to set different game values depending on which difficulty you enter as a parameter.

With the TextView error, are you sure that the question_label exists in your Layout xml?

Comment: Hi Knossos, Yes the getPuzzle() method is suppose to return the type of questions that are to be asked to the user. The point of the game is to display 10 questions in each difficulty, where the harder the difficulty, the more equations in the question.  So its like if the user picks easy, then in the getPuzzle() method it would call the Easy12() method.  But for some reason I can't call the Easy12 method in the switch statement of getPuzzle(), that is my only problem right now apart from the TextView not displaying anything.

Comment: Yes the label does exist in XML, I think the problem is setting the text or something. Would greatly appreciate your or anybody else's input.

Answer (score 0):

Yeeeyy I got it now, the problem was that my setContentView(R.layout.gamelayout); was after declaring a method that sets the TextView object, making it not recognize it. So I moved it up under the super.onCreate and its working. :)

Thanks TheLastBert and Knossoss for helping me realize the problem.